# Does someboody ever used google map as tracking device

Tags: android

When Google map starts it give location of the device using device id or its imie no. .
Is there any method so that we can set this device info programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION